# Python 3.5 if statement on nested dict data : TypeError

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

```
if story['epic']['id'] == epic['id']:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Code:

```
for epic in epics:
    if epic['archived'] is False:
        print(epic['short_name'], epic['summary'], epic['story_count'])
        for story in stories:
            if story['epic']['id'] == epic['id']:
                    print(story['summary'], story['cell']['label'])
```

I'm probably going about this all wrong, but still trying to learn json/dict iterations and how to compare between multiple ones.

I'm trying to retrieve data from stories that match ID to the same epic ID. I know that the `story['epic']` contains `['id']` and `['local_id']` under it but apparently I'm unable to compare that with non stories dict data?

Note: The value of `story['epic']['id']` could be nothing.

Comment: The error message is telling you that either `story`, `story['epic'`], or `epic` is equal to `None`; you might start by finding out which it is.

Comment: You can find the problem by inserting `print(epic)` and `print(story)` just before the problematic `if`

Comment: Either `story` or `store['epic']` is `None`, so the next `[...]` part of the expression is applied to that object and not to a dictionary. You'll have to figure out which one and how to deal with that.

Comment: oh, so the actual list could be none in story or story['epic']. ok that's a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most JSON libraries convert their input into nested `dict`s. However, unless the source is very kind, when dealing with JSON inputs you almost always have to deal with the fact that objects may be omitted.

The best way to handle this is to use `dict.get()` rather than directly subscripting the resulting `dict` as it allows you to provide a default if the key is missing.

Thus, instead of `story['epic']['id']` you can do

```
story_id = story.get('epic', {}).get('id', "")
```

This will either return the story's `id` value if present, or an empty string. Either way, you can then safely compare it to `epic['id']`

Note that all your intermediate steps should return an empty `dict` as the default - allowing the chain of calls to continue without raising an exception.

```
mydict.get('k1',{}).get('k1.1',{}).get('k1.1.1`,{}).get('lastkey','default')
```

If you find yourself doing this in enough places to seem repetitive (and you will :) you can always abstract it into a utility function

```
def getnested(thedict,intermediate_keys,final_key,dflt):
    dd = thedict
    for key in intermediate_keys:
        dd = dd.get(key,{})
    return dd.get(final_key,dflt)
```

And call it thus

```
getnested(story,['epic'], 'id', 'missing')
getnested(mydict,['k1','k1.1','k1.1.1'],'lastkey','default')
```

Comment: very helpful in getting that working. Thank you for the clarifying the utility function example. I currently have 7 places this is being repeated so that should help in reduction of code changes.

Answer (score -1):

This just means that, either

`story['epic']` is a None Object or 
`epic['id']` is a None Object.

Then the error message makes sense now and you should be able to figure out the reason for this in the logic of your code.

Comment: How is this different to Martijn's comment above?

Comment: @kdopen  - I did not read the comment. Comments are meant for clarification and not answering. :)